# Unable to write Spark's DataFrame to hive using presto

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, hive, presto

I'm writing some code to save a DataFrame to a hive database using presto

```
df.write.format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:presto://myurl/hive?user=user/default")
  .option("driver","com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver")
  .option("dbtable", "myhivetable")
  .mode("overwrite")
  .save()
```

this actually must work , but  this actually raises an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for array<string>
```